# Python: efficient syntax for creating a list composed of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I am new to python and essentially trying to figure out the syntax that replicates this functionality: `strings = ["foo", "bar", "apple"]` with something similar to `strings = [foo, bar, apple]` so that I don't have to put quotes around all the entries. Thanks!

Comment: you can put the entries in a sqlite database first, if there are that many of them that typing the quotes is going to be an issue.

Comment: sorry, but this is just awkward. Why would you do such a thing. If it's a string then put quotes around it, so the interpreter knows its a string. Else how do you think the interpreter can find out what you mean? There is no looking glass which guesses your intentions. Quotes in python, c[#,++,..], java, scala, ...and so on are just a syntactic construct to express, this is a string.

Comment: @evildead: To be honest, I can sympathize. Having to put an extra comma and two extra quotes between each element is quite ugly and hard to read compared to `"foo bar baz".split()`, and equally readable once used to it.

Comment: @delnan: The answer of DNS expresses exactly what I was thinking when reading this question. The split maybe a nice solution for his problem, but from my point of view it's just ugly.

Comment: `dict(foo=None, bar=None, apple=None).keys()` ... hehehe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strings = "foo bar apple".split()
```

Comment: if the string I get initially is a csv file, would I instead do strings = "foo, bar, apple".split(", ")?

Comment: if you initially have csv file, then use csv module from the stdlib, it will save several days of your life.

Answer (score 2):

```
strings = r"foo, bar, apple".split(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place all the strings in a text file, one string on each line.  Then `strings = list(open("datafile", "r"))`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is no easier way to create a list of strings than what you're already doing.

As other answers have pointed out, there are ways to put all the strings in one big string or file, then split them, but in my opinion that is more difficult to type than the quotes, particularly if you have a decent IDE that automatically closes string quotes.  Also, the syntax you're already using is what anyone else who reads your code will expect; using something else just adds unnecessary confusion for almost zero gain.

Comment: exactly. Nothing more to add.

Comment: I am receiving the string in a format that I cannot control. The string comes to me in this format and therefore I was looking for the easiest transformation.

Comment: than you should have written this in the question itself. For me it reads like, hey guys tell me how to get rid of quoting strings, I'm too lazy too write quotes and commas. :) Maybe I and DNS interpreted a way too much in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is two major differences between what you posted:

The quotes "" and '' indicate that it is a string, just like [1,2,3] would be a list of integers. If you remove the quotes, you are essentially creating a list of python objects. A python object is basically the foundation of all python classes, e.g. integers and strings are python objects are their most basic level.

You can do something like:

```
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
apple = "apple"
strings = [foo,bar,apple]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of elements to write, you can use a program to do that (such an incredible idea from a developper ! ), and then you copy-paste the result:

```
li = []

ch = ("You have entered an empty string ''\n"
      'Type ENTER alone if you want to stop.\n'
      'Type anything if you want to record the empty string : ')

while True:
    e = raw_input('enter : ')
    if e=='':
        x = raw_input(ch)
        if x=='':  break
    li.append(e)

print
print li
```

Example:

```
enter : 123
enter : ocean
enter : flower
enter : 
You have entered an empty string ''
Type ENTER alone if you want to stop.
Type anything if you want to record the empty string : k
enter : once upon a time
enter : 14 * 4
enter : 
You have entered an empty string ''
Type ENTER alone if you want to stop.
Type anything if you want to record the empty string : 

['123', 'ocean', 'flower', '', 'once upon a time', '14 * 4']
```

What you have not to type but only copy is:

```
['123', 'ocean', 'flower', '', 'once upon a time', '14 * 4']
```